# How do I get the width of a GLuint texture?

Tags: c++, c, opengl, sdl, textures

I was wondering how I get the width of a GLuint Texture in OpenGL. Could someone please tell me? and maybe give me a link to somewhere that has these things mapped out?

Answer (score 8):

Bind the texture and call glGetTexLevelParameter to get the width, you can get other parameters using the same call:

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetTexLevelParameter.xml

Comment: It says glGetTexLevelParameter was not declared in this scope. what do I have to include to use this?

Comment: @CyanPrime: `glGetTexLevelParameter` is not the name of the actual function, it's just the common prefix of the actual function names `glGetTexLevelParameterfv` and `glGetTexLevelParameteriv`, which take pointers to `float` arrays and `int` arrays respectively.  Since the texture width is an integer, you want to use `glGetTexLevelParameteriv`.